# OpenAI gym player mode

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openair

Does anyone know how to run one of the OpenAI gym environments as a player. As in letting a human player play a round of cart pole? I have seen that there is env.mode = 'human' but I have not been able to get it to run properly. I have tried to follow the example given here https://www.pinchofintelligence.com/getting-started-openai-gym/ but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to enable play mode for the environments.

https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/utils/play.py

Answer (score 5):

I was experimenting with this today, hope this helps:

```
env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
gym.utils.play.play(env, zoom=3)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'gym.utils' has no attribute 'play' :s

Comment: Try `from gym.utils import play` and then `play.play(gym.make('Breakout-v0'), zoom=3)`

Answer (score 3):

The [openai/gym](https://github.com/openai/gym) repo has been moved to the [gymnasium](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium) repo.

```
PROMPT> pip install "gymnasium[atari, accept-rom-license]"
```

In order to launch a game in a playable mode. Start python in interactive mode, like this:

```
PROMPT> python
```

Then paste the following, line by line:

```py
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium.utils.play import play
env = gym.make('ALE/Breakout-v5', render_mode='rgb_array')
play(env, zoom=3)
```

Keymap

- Key `a` moves left.
- Key `d` moves right.
- Key `space` is fire.

To quit the game

```py
exit()
```

More info on the Gymnasium `Breakout` page:
https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/atari/breakout/

It's not all environments that supports `render_mode="rgb_array"` and may fail to launch.

Comment: a game just plays on its one. How to make it pause and let a player to do something?

Comment: what environment are you trying to get working? Some environments have a `"human"` mode that may be interactive.

Comment: that is "Blackjack-v1" on "Toy Text". I do not see the relevant the option. The game just runs on its own.

Comment: Since `play()` rely on the `rgb_array` mode, and if that mode isn't playable with `Blackjack-v1`. then you may have to code your own keybinding to action wrapper for `render_mode='human'`. https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium/blob/main/gymnasium/envs/toy_text/blackjack.py